# Inability to authenticate and download the list of Word documents at SharePoint server by using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have the script which retrieves all links to Word documents from the SharePoint server with the specified text. After the list of documents copies to the local drive.

```
$siteAddress = "http://d/D/O%20S/S/O/S/"
$invokeData = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $siteAddress -UseDefaultCredentials).Links.Href| Select-String "/Dev/O/S/OS2017-1/S/"
foreach ($item in $invokeData)
{
  $filename = "http://docs" + $item
  $ssLDocName = Split-path $item -Leaf
  $ssLDocName2 = "D:\FF\" + $ssLocalDocName
  $userName = "John Doe"
  $passWord = Get-Content D:\Password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
  $C = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
  Start-BitsTransfer -Credential $C -Source $filename -Destination $ssLocalDocName
}
```

When I executed it I get the error message

```
Start-BitsTransfer : HTTP status 401: The requested resource requires user authentication.
```

I thought that problem with an incorrect login. I tried the different varieties. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code to download file from SharePoint 2013 by PowerShell.

Hope it helps

```
    Function Download-File([string]$FileUrl,[string]$DownloadPath)
 {    
    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FileUrl)
    $downloadFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($DownloadPath,$fileName)


    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $client.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("lee", "password", "domain")    
    $client.DownloadFile($FileUrl, $downloadFilePath)
    $client.Dispose()
}

Download-File -FileUrl http://sp:12001/MyDoc3/TestLee.pdf -DownloadPath "C:\Lee\PSDownLoad"
```

Comment: I slightly updated your function and it works like a charm! It especially useful to pass credentials to SharePoint.